# Invalid column lower(substr(displayname,1,1)) in android Q

Tags: android

I m Using pixel phone android 10(Q) version,  I m trying to get media file name and grouping. I got some error "**Invalid column lower(substr(displayname,1,1)) in android 10** ". It is only happening in the android 10 version, the below version is working fine.

**CODE**

String selection = selectionArgs.first;

projection={"lower(substr(" + MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + ",1,1))",MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME , "COUNT(*) AS COUNT"} ;

String queryKey="lower(substr(" + MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + ",1,1))";

selection += ") GROUP BY (" + queryKey;

cursor = contentResolver.query(uri,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs.second,
                    null);

**ERROR**

**Invalid column lower(substr(displayname,1,1))**

Comment: you have problems with quotes there

Comment: I added quotes but it is not working

Comment: you likely added them in wrong place

Comment: it is working  in below  android 10 version, My problem is android Q version I m getting this  "Invalid column lower(substr(displayname,1,1))" error when i use this "lower(substr( "sql Querry

Answer (score 0):

SQL Keywords are no longer allowed in projections from Android Q onwards. Have a look at this issue:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130965914

Using a combination of requesting just one column and then using [Cursor.getCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getCount()) might help although I have not tried it. I expect that you might need to have to deal with the new RecoverableSecurityException when doing this